# Making one Option[List[MyType]] from three different Option[List[MyType]]

Tags: scala

I have

```
def searchListProducts1 = models.Products.IndivProduct.getProductsFromJsObjectList(productsTextSearchDescription)
def searchListProducts2 = models.Products.IndivProduct.getProductsFromJsObjectList(productsTextSearchName)
def searchListProducts3 = models.Products.IndivProduct.getProductsFromJsObjectList(productsTextSearchIngredients)
```

where each is Option[List[MyType]]

I want to "merge" them all together (is that a fold?) so that I have just one Option[List[MyType]]

Thanks

Comment: Wrapping `List` within `Option` seems redundant.. is there any reason for having `None` instead of just an empty `List`?

Comment: I suppose not. Except that I can case match on None..

Comment: You could match `Nil` for an empty list.

Answer (score 3):

As others have suggested, `Option[List[T]]` is redundant, unless you have a very good reason for preferring a `None` to a `Nil`. Just lose the `Option` and do:

```
searchListProducts1 ++ searchListProducts2 ++ searchListProducts3
```

or

```
List(searchListProducts1, searchListProducts2, searchListProducts3).flatten
```

---

If you really want to keep the `Option` wrapper for some reason:

```
(searchListProducts1 ++ searchListProducts2 ++ searchListProducts3).flatten
```

or

```
List(searchListProducts1, searchListProducts2, searchListProducts3).flatten.flatten
```

Why the weird double `flatten`? Because it's weird to wrap `List` into `Option` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be this:

```
case class MyType(a: Int)

def searchListProducts1: Option[List[MyType]] = ???
def searchListProducts2: Option[List[MyType]] = ???
def searchListProducts3: Option[List[MyType]] = ???

val listed = List(searchListProducts1, searchListProducts2, searchListProducts3)

val merged: Option[List[MyType]] = Option(
  listed.foldLeft(List(): List[MyType])((acc, curr) => curr match {
    case Some(list) => acc ++ list
    case None => acc
  })
)
```

Another (better I think) way:

```
val listed = List(searchListProducts1, searchListProducts2, searchListProducts3)

listed.map(_.getOrElse(List())).reduce(_ ++ _)
```

But as LimboSoup said I would drop the `Option` since it seems redundant, you could easily get an empty list instead of wrapping it up in an option.